# Can I deploy multiple cordapps on the same machine

Tags: corda

According to documentation many cordapps can be deployed to a single node that lives in `/opt/corda`. Can I deploy additional nodes on the same VM?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each node gets its own base directory under `/opt`. You can have N number of nodes on a single VM. For example:

- `/opt/PartyA`
- `/opt/PartyB`
- etc

Each node must have it's own entry in `systemctl` have the service started.

If all nodes are running the same application you can put all configuration in the same base directory. However, this is more difficult because each node must specify its own configuration `-config-file foo.conf`, database, certificates, message queue, etc.